# Do you know any file comparison add-in for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, diff, add-in

Is there any built-in, add-in solution for visual studio to compare two files and display result with differences? I could't find one...

Comment: retagged to 'diff', since that's the lingo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use [WinMerge](http://www.winmerge.org). Not as good as Beyond Compare but it's free and open source.

Also check out [Visual Studio Comparison Tools](http://www.codeplex.com/ComparisonTools), it's a Visual Studio add-in that connects it to WinMerge.

Comment: I highly recommend the Visual Studio Comparison Tools!  I use it with WinMerge as well.

Comment: *Never* use WinMerge to do a merge, only diffs. It's unable to handle 3-way merges.

Answer (score 14):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmanning/diffmerge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values) is an excellent post that describes integration of many 3rd party diff and merge tools into Visual Studio - including araxis, beyond compare, WinMerge and many others. The post is badly needed, since the command-line parameters that VS can supply aren't fully documented.

Personally, I switched from the built-in tool to Araxis, and am generally happy with it.  I am also curious about bazaar, which supposedly ([according to the colorful author of its diff-component](http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/37690.html)), "solves the diff problem"...
Anyone has any experience with that?

Answer (score 4):

As for me, [CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) is a useful solution for your task. You can
compare, merge and edit data within one environment  - in the Visual Studio.

Comment: CodeCompare seems to be awesome!! However, I recently found it, installed it and threw it away like half an hour later. The reason: It is currently totally unstable in VS 2010. Running multiple instances of VS 2010 results in comparison windows opening in the wrong instance (wtf?) and after running a comparison the window opens and then leads to VS 2010 crashing immediately. These phenomenons occur on my system... doesn't necessarily mean that they happen on others' systems too. :) I will try it out in a couple of weeks/months when 2.0 is RTM again.

Comment: I've tried last version of CodeCompare. It is very well as for me. Interaction with VS 2010 was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [djeidot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4880/djeidot)'s answer: beware if you're using Visual Studio 2010, [Visual Studio Comparison Tools](http://www.codeplex.com/ComparisonTools) works very well with VS 2008, but does not under VS 2010...

Comment: Is there any new tool for this?

Comment: @LnDCobra, the tool was updated and it works fine with VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition has a built in version (based on WinDiff?) but you can incorporate third party tools e.g.

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) which I regularly use.

See [here](http://elegantdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/03/visual-studio-file-comparison-settings.html) for how-to.

Answer (score 1):

That functionality appears to be related to Source Control.  So it is really as source control issue.

If you are not using Source Control - You should be - Try The Vault from [www.sourcegear.com](http://www.sourcegear.com) for a good (and free for one user) commercial source control system.  There are others and they should come with a comparision tool (The Vault has one and its installed into VS when you install the vault client and connect to a source controlled project).

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) is probably worth a look anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case I'd recommend VisualSVN.  You'll get the source control feature of SVN built into the VS IDE plus the ability to compare any source code file with any checked in version file from SVN.

It installs all the prerequites for you SVN (Subversion), TortoiseSVN, Diff, AND VisualSVN (The Visual Studio Integration).

It also has a nice quick windows installer for the SVN server which worries about apache etc. so you don't have to.

Essential for the non linux geek, it it not free but at $49 it is a bargain,

http://www.visualsvn.com/

Answer (score 0):

SlickEdit Tools Versioning Toolbox has the same diff tool built in as the SlickEdit programmer's editor.  The Versioning Toolbox is not free but isn't that expensive either.  The diff tool is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add some version control plugin to visual studio, you can select the tool for diff.
Perforce are giving away their diff and merge tool for free, it is very good and you don't have to be using the perforce version control system to be using it. one can download it from their site; it is called p4merge. when running the installer you should only select the feature "Visual Merge Tool (P4Merge)" and unselect the other features which are only relevant if you are using perforce.

personally I use vim because it do syntax coloring (which I feel is very helpful especially when you do diff or merge) but it has a steep learning curve.